# how to export to html using multiple css

Tags: html, export, css

I have to convert many notebooks to HTML so I'm trying to create all possible rules so to minimize the manual correction. The html pages need to have multiple css links, something like the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[path]css1.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[path]css2.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[path]css3.css" type="text/css" />
```

So, I know there is the option "CSS" for HTML export but it takes only one string, like the following

```
Export["test.html", EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML", "CSS"->"[path]css1.css"]
```

but it doesn't accept a list of strings, like

```
Export["test.html", EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML", "CSS"->{"[path]css1.css", "[path]css2.css"}]
```

Is there any alternative?

Comment: If you put css files on the the wolfram cloud they are not served with a mime type text/css. If your main html file is also set to public. Still you're stuck with the wrong mime type served. If you upload your css files to any webserver and externally link to them it will work.

Comment: @pvanbijnen thanks for the answer. Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean. I cannot consider Wolfram cloud because this code is part of more complex webMathematica project hosted on company's server. I just need to specify more than one css when exporting the html from a Mathematica notebook. Of course, I can add the css manually after export. but having them written by Mathematica would be great.